# SQL query pivot values to new columns at change in value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for help with a query relating to staff clocking in/out.

My code is currently:

```
SELECT CAST(EVENTTIME AS Date) AS Date, FORMAT(EVENTTIME, 'HH:mm') AS Time,SUM(UserID) AS UserID, FirstName + Space(1) + Surname, EventSubTypeDescription
FROM EventsEx
WHERE EventTime >= '2022-05-09' AND (PeripheralName ='clock (In)' OR PeripheralName ='clock (Out)')
GROUP BY userid, EventTime, FirstName, Surname, EventSubTypeDescription
ORDER BY Date,UserID, Time ASC
```

Which results in:

| Date | Time | UserID | UserName | EventSubTypeDescription |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-09 | 07:53 | 393 | Jennifer | Clock in |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:33 | 393 | Jennifer | Clock out |
| 2022-05-09 | 14:06 | 393 | Jennifer | Clock in |
| 2022-05-09 | 16:57 | 393 | Jennifer | Clock out |
| 2022-05-09 | 07:59 | 401 | agency 2 | Clock in |
| 2022-05-09 | 12:58 | 401 | agency 2 | Clock out |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:27 | 401 | agency 2 | Clock in |
| 2022-05-09 | 16:56 | 401 | agency 2 | Clock out |
| 2022-05-09 | 07:57 | 422 | Tash | Clock in |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:56 | 422 | Tash | Clock out |
| 2022-05-09 | 07:58 | 432 | agency 4 | Clock in |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:00 | 432 | agency 4 | Clock out |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:30 | 432 | agency 4 | Clock in |
| 2022-05-09 | 16:56 | 432 | agency 4 | Clock out |
| 2022-05-09 | 07:57 | 434 | Jordan | Clock in |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:32 | 434 | Jordan | Clock out |
| 2022-05-09 | 14:03 | 434 | Jordan | Clock in |
| 2022-05-09 | 16:59 | 434 | Jordan | Clock out |
| 2022-05-09 | 07:59 | 438 | Adam | Clock in |
| 2022-05-09 | 12:59 | 438 | Adam | Clock out |
| 2022-05-09 | 13:29 | 438 | Adam | Clock in |
| 2022-05-09 | 16:56 | 438 | Adam | Clock out |

Each user clocks in and out during the day.  I need to move the Times to separate columns therefore each user has one row per day.

| Date | UserID | Username | EventSubTypeDescription | Clock in | Clock Out | Clock in 2 | Clock out 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 09/05/2022 | 393 | Jennifer | Clock in | 07:53 | 13:33 | 14:06 | 16:57 |
| 09/05/2022 | 401 | agency 2 | Clock in | 07:59 | 12:58 | 13:27 | 16:56 |
| 09/05/2022 | 422 | Tash | Clock in | 07:57 | 13:56 |  |  |
| 09/05/2022 | 432 | agency 4 | Clock in | 07:58 | 13:00 | 13:30 | 16:56 |
| 09/05/2022 | 434 | Jordan | Clock in | 07:57 | 13:32 | 14:03 | 16:59 |
| 09/05/2022 | 438 | Adam | Clock in | 07:59 | 12:59 | 13:29 | 16:56 |

Comment: can you share your sample input data that correspond to the output you provided?

Comment: Hi, sorry not sure what you mean as this is coming from a Sql table, which I can't share, thanks

Comment: I phrased it wrong: can you share sample inputs from the `EventsEx` table that allow you to get the output you shared? @Adam

Comment: Hi, unfortunately the db login does not show the table (I've asked for increased permissions) I can only currently see the db fields and query on it

Answer (score 0):

Beginning from your current output table, you can assign a column number to each of your row, by partitioning on the specific date and user. Then extract the values for `clock in`, `clock out`, `clock in 2`, `clock out 2` separately using MAX function over CASE construct:

```
SELECT Date,
       UserID,
       Username,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ColNum=1 THEN Time ELSE NULL END) AS Clock_in,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ColNum=2 THEN Time ELSE NULL END) AS Clock_out,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ColNum=3 THEN Time ELSE NULL END) AS Clock_in_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ColNum=4 THEN Time ELSE NULL END) AS Clock_out_2
FROM (SELECT *,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Date, UserID 
                               ORDER     BY Time         ) ColNum
      FROM output_table) ranked_clock_events
GROUP BY Date,
         UserID,
         Username
ORDER BY UserID
```

Try it [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=df4a03745201401b09a2ad840238d9e4).

*Side Note 1*: to use this query with your query, it's sufficient to replace your code in place of `output table`

*Side Note 2*: For a better query that avoids you an intermediate result (given by the `output_table` result set), ping me here in case you manage to obtain the `EventEx` table.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Will see if I can get better db access. thanks